# Converting a form text input into a select option dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, input

I'm trying to convert the following text field input into a dropdown menu with options.

```
<form id='reForm' method='post' name='form2' action='index.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input size='32' type='text' class='textinput5' name='city' value='<?php print $reCity; ?>' id='reCity'>
</form>
```

This is what I've come up with and it doesn't work :/

```
<select class='textinput5' name='city' value='<?php print $reCity; ?>' id='reCity'>
    <option value="montreal">Montreal</option>
    <option value="california">California</option>
</select>
```

Any Ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A select can not have a value. If you want a value selected, you must add that to the option, not the selected. So `<option value="montreal" selected>Montreal</option>`

You will probably need to squeeze an if statement in each option.

If I remember PHP

```
<option value="montreal" <? if($reCity == 'montreal'){echo 'selected'; }?>>Montreal</option>
```

I think you can do something close to that. My syntax is most likely wrong.